# Show value from variable with stars (*)

Tags: bash

I had problem with my variable in loop. I use ssh for connected to remote server and on server I need to read file line by line. Variable can obtains for example some string or cron ( 1 * * * *). When variable contains stars I cannot show this value.

```
ssh -p $PORT -t $USER@IP  bash -c "

        while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "\$line" ]]; do
            echo 'Text read from file: \$line;
        done < $SAVED_CONFIGURATION
    "
```

Comment: **The solution is:**
I must give before while set -f.  Now it's working

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question and click on the accept button. This way others know the issue is solved. Comments are not the way to do that. You might even get upvotes for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: I must give before while set -f. Now it's working